# Laravel OrderBy Relationship count with pagination

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, query-builder

I have many projects and each has many orders, some completed, some not.

I want to order them by the amount of completed orders like this:

```
$products = $products->orderBy(function($product) {
    return $product->orders->where('status', 2)->count();
})->paginate(15);
```

I know the order call doesn't work like this but this is the best was show the problem. SortBy doesn't work because I want to use pagination.

Comment: What's the version of your laravel?

Comment: Don't return inside your function because that will stop your query.

Comment: I know this code is wrong. You can't pass `orderBy`a function because it has to convert it to an database query. But it explains the problem I have.

Comment: So you want to sort your products based on the count of status that is equal to two am I right?

Comment: @aldrin27 that's right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally found a good solution for the problem:

```
$products = $products->join('orders', function ($join) {
                        $join->on('orders.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
                            ->where('orders.status', '=', 2);
                    })
                    ->groupBy('products.id')
                    ->orderBy('count', $order)
                    ->select((['products.*', DB::raw('COUNT(orders.product_id) as count')]))->paginate(50);
```

Comment: Nice one. I have generalized this into a scope, so you could do "$products->includeCount('orders')->orderBy('orders', 'desc')". Have a look

https://gist.github.com/boukeversteegh/50c138578c9ca4b9282491b274db5d16

Comment: have other solution whitout the `->join()` that uses `with()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it works:

```
    $categories = Prodcuts::with(array('orders' => function($query) {
       $query->select(DB::raw('SELECT * count(status) WHERE status = 2 as count'))
        $query->orderBy('MAX(count)')
     }))->paginate(15);

    return View::make('products.index', compact('categories'));
```

**Note:** This is not tested.

Comment: ` Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT * count(status) WHERE status = 2 as count from `orders` where `orders`.`p' at line 1 (SQL: select SELECT * count(status) WHERE status = 2 as count from `orders` where `orders`.`product_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15) order by `MAX(count)` asc)`

Answer (score 0):

From 5.2 on wards you can use the `withCount` for counting relationship result.

In this case the

```
$products = $products->withCount(['orders' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('status', 2);
}]);
```

Reference : https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships